# Logback support in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I have tried to add logback in Quarkus, but later realised Quarkus does not support logback. If I am wrong, May I know how logback can be configured in Quarkus with an example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Quarkus extension which enables logback: https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-logging-logback/dev/index.html

However there are some restrictions, mostly due to internal Quarkus specifics:

1. Your Quarkus version should match version used for 'quarkus-logging-logback' extension build
2. If you want to use own appenders/listeners in 'logback.xml' - you should put them in separate library and include them in your project through library

Comment: This is correct. For me, I had to pin the logback version to 0.13.0. Then, just simply added the logback.xml to resources and that was it

Answer (score 0):

No, in Quarkus, we standardized on using JBoss Logging for the logging.

And AFAIK we don't even have a bridge from logback to JBoss Logging as for some other logging components so you can't even use the Logback API in your application.

Comment: Why is it then that logback is managed in the quarkus-bom (3.2.6)? We are facing weird issues with losing MDCs and it seems to be related to logging-backends used.

Answer (score 0):

In currrent version 1.6.0.final of Quarkus You can use one of the Logging API's below

- JDK java.util.logging
- JBoss Logging
- SLF4J
- Apache Commons Logging

https://quarkus.io/guides/logging

Comment: Logback implements SFL4J. Any library or code that logs to Logback actually logs to SLF4J and can therefore run on Quarkus. However, a logback.xml configuration doesn't work on Quarkus (yet?).